# How do I structure a presentation in Impress libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice-impress

Coming from a latex background I would like to make presentation in Impress/Libreoffice.

I wonder if there is a feature to structure the presentation as it is possible in Latex/Beamer package.

I could not find a description in the manual. 
While structuring text is possible in writer, is this feature missing Impress?

EDIT:
I would like to structure the presentation into sections.

- Section 1: Outline
- Section 2: Motivation
- Section 3: Approach
- Section 4: Implementation
- Section 5: Tests
- Section 6: Results
- Section 7: Perspective.

These sections should show on the header or foot section of the slide.  They could also appear on a side bar in each  slide.

I will not have a lot of equations in this talk so I was hoping to use Impress instead of beamer.

[image: Beamer example]

When writing an article in Writer, I can also set a `Heading 1`, `Heading 2`, `Chapter 1`, Chapter 2` and so on. I wonder why this is missing in impress.

Comment: Could you describe exactly what you need fir those od us not familiar with Beamer?

Comment: If you mean styles, Impress has them under the format menu (or press 
F11)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this with Impress.
Impress lacks this feature!

Comment: I feel like upvoting and downvoting this answer at the same time :-(

Comment: Its 10 years now and it seems this feature is still not there (using Impress 7.6.3.2). Seems not many people actually want that otherwise it would be there by now.